# How to make an array then accessing its elements as reference using C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-forms-designer

I am working on a project using C# windows forms.
I want to change a Label.Text by putting it in array then i want to access this labels by the array and change its text.

I tried to do this but it isn't working.

```
int*[] Labels = new int*[30];
```

but this message appears:

> pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in unsafe context

So, any one can help?

I tried to make array of pointers then access it by reference but can't do it?

Comment: *"I want to change a Label.Text by putting it in array then i want to access this labels by the array and change its text."* your code example does not show you using the `Label.Text` anywhere. Perhaps you are wanting to do [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can have the labels update automatically when some other variable updates.

Comment: OK, exactly this what i want thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c# you are not allowed to work with pointers usually, but if you want to , you have to use unsafe block.
That is you have to put code that does pointer manipulations inside the unsafe block.
eg:unsafe{
code....
}
For more info : [unsafe code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx)

In visual studio you also have to go to the project settings and enable unsafe code.